# Mounting host volumes in development container

Tags: visual-studio-code, docker-desktop, vscode-devcontainer

I have created a development container with some custom dependency compilation. After a few hours building it is time to run my first tests. My tests require loading files that are on the host disk (pretrained models and some data), in a separate folder. Running with tools like docker compose or docker command line I can share files of the host with the container by specifying volumes. The development container does the same with the code folder, but how can I specify additional volumes for development containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Multi Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) for that:

Say you have a `docker-compose.yml` file where you have a base configuration for all your environments (dev, prod, etc.):

```
web:
  image: example/my_web_app:latest
  ports:
    - "1234:1234"
```

And then you have other environment files like `docker-compose.env.yml` where you add or override configuration based on the environment.

With your example, you'd have a `docker-compose.dev.yml` where you'd add the additional volumes required for your development containers:

```
web:
  volumes:
    - 'path/to/host/folder:/path/to/container/folder'
```

During development, you would then launch your stack with:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d
```

Note: make sure to check how properties are handled when overriding files [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understand-the-extends-configuration), and especially [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#adding-and-overriding-configuration) in your case.

Edit: now to use several docker-compose.yml files in your `devcontainer.json`, use the [dockerComposeFile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/create-dev-container#_extend-your-docker-compose-file-for-development) property. Here you'll remove the "build" property and supply a list of docker-compose files:

```
...
  "dockerComposeFile": [
    "path/to/docker-compose.yml",
    "path/to/docker-compose.dev.yml"
  ],
  "service": "web",
  "shutdownAction": "stopCompose",
...
```

/!\ Note that the order of the files is important since later files override previous ones.

Comment: Reading the [devcontainerjson reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference#_image-or-dockerfile-specific-properties) I see mounts, I was trying it, and now it required my image to be rebuilt, this will take about 2 hours :/

Comment: I think it solved the problem, what is missing in your answer is to mention how to change the `devcontainer.json` to use a docker file instead of a build: {...} as in the auto generated configuration (I filled this with other resources). I will accept after you improve the description of the steps. Thank you

Comment: @Bob great to know it solved your issue. I added clarifications as to how to use it with `devcontainer.json`.

Comment: now i have lost the `/workspaces/project` folder